# b-form-input trigger event on leave

Tags: javascript, html, forms, events, bootstrap-4

I have a `<b-form-input>` whose purpose is to verify the input when the user leaves that specific field via pressing `tab`, or clicking the mouse outside that field, or any event as long as it leaves that field.

Question: How do I trigger a method for this events?

**I'm using Vue, maybe there's any other way to solve it in a vue way?**

Comment: @blex Thanks mate, made it simpler by adding this in my `<b-form-input .. @blur.native="handleBlur"`